# Is it possible to do Android with ATG(Art Technology Group)..?

Tags: android, atg

Is it possible to do a Android application with ATG technology. i googled for how to integrate ATG with android but i dint get any proper guidance. I searched for sample source file also but none is available in google. can anyone suggest me a good tutorials for accessing ATG with Android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATG has this framework called ATG Mobile. They have introduced it for Android applications now. They had it for iPhone earlier. The TommyHilfiger iPhone app is built on ATG Mobile.

Comment: Thank you mr Bell,I knew about TommyGilfigure iphone app.  Do you have any references or any tutorials relates to ATG android..??

Comment: I heard they removed this framework when Oracle came in to the picture. I used it and felt that it was a little heavy. I would start with a basic HTML mobile site and embed it within a WebView and use the JavaScript interface

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to give an update on this, yes it is possible to use oracle atg 
with android. I will give you the steps.
Install oracle Atg. It comes pre installed with eclipse indigo inside so make sure you enable this. I am not sure if the android sdk is included so you can go 
to the eclipse marketplace located inside oracle atg and install this.... 
Oracle should have mentioned this but the best way to learn about programming 
android is going to the  spring framework site and find documents about spring 
android and follow the spring restful pattern. oracle atg web commerce follows the portlets 
pattern however they use droplets instead of servlets. here is documentation
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10543653

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1301usingrestwebservices01.html

Answer (score 0):

ATG provides a REST Web Services framework.  You should use this framework to invoke services in ATG.  The REST Web Services framework includes a Java client library.  In Android you would include that library in your Android app to invoke REST services.

Answer (score 0):

ATG Provides a REST framework, and has some Mobile-specific modules. It can be a bit difficult to work with ATG's services.

Take a look at Mobile Cube (http://www.deliverycube.com). It is a new framework, and much more focussed towards mobile client applications